How to access web app in internal network on ubuntu
A web application is running on ubuntu machine on port 7777.
I am trying to access this web app in internal network.
I have tried to open port using:
sudo ufw allow 7777

and I get relevant status
 To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----                      
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
7777                       ALLOW       Anywhere                   
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
7777 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)   

still I can not reach the app through internal network.
I also changed this config net.ipv4.ip_forward=1.
What can be done to share localhost web apps through internal network.

[so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.


Try this command to allow port with tcp protocol: sudo ufw allow 7777/tcp

If above command not works, Try with disabling firewall for testing purpose
# sudo ufw disable 
If it work's, When disabling firewall, Let me know ?

If incase, after disabling firewall also, If it not work's, Please try by checking network connectivity, Between to VM's by using ping and telnet command's


I hope this will solve your problem.

Please don't answer off-topic questions; thanks.
